# Wordpress when loop condition done add filter to the_content()

Tags: wordpress, for-loop, add-filter

We have a box div, Need add it to top or bottom of content,

so how we can us this loop inside add_filter ('the_content', 'box div');

this is our loop

```
    if (is_array($my_box_pos)) {
        foreach ($my_box_pos as $key => $val) {
            if ( $val[moz]=="bottom"  || $val[moz]=="top_and_bottom" )
            sandy_box($bottom);
        }
    }
```

this is content filter

```
function content_sample($content) {
    if( is_singular() && is_main_query() ) {
        $new_content = '<p>This is added to the bottom of all post and page content, as well as custom post types.</p>';
        $content .= $new_content;   
    }   
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'content_sample');
```

someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
function content_sample($content) {
    if( is_singular() && is_main_query() ) {
        $new_content = '<p>This is added to the bottom of all post and page content, as well as custom post types.</p>';
        if (is_array($my_box_pos)) {
             foreach ($my_box_pos as $key => $val) {
               if ( $val[moz]=="bottom"  || $val[moz]=="top_and_bottom" )
                $content .= $new_content;
               }
               else { $content = $new_content . $content; }
             }

       }   
       return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'content_sample');
```

Try this, I am not sure if it works for you.